# Notification when Terminal is ready/finished - Applescript

Tags: macos, notifications, terminal, applescript

is there a way to get notified when terminal finished a command?

-> I run another script(not mine!) which downloads data when this script finished I want to quit terminal and do other stuff with this data.

**EDIT:**
I may didnt ask correctly...

Example:

```
tell application "Terminal"
   keystroke "php downloadscript.php"
   keystroke return
end tell
```

if (downloadFinished)
   -- do stuff
else
   -- wait till finished

**Edit 2:**
Awesome! Thank you!
Working like that:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
        delay 1
    end repeat
    #display dialog "finished"
end tell
```

greetings
hatschii

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terminal's Dock icon starts bouncing when a tab prints \a and the tab is not focused or Terminal is not frontmost:

```
sleep 5; printf '\a'
```

You could also run something like `afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Blow.aiff`. Or use terminal-notifier:

```
sudo gem install terminal-notifier
terminal-notifier -message ''
```

You can wait until a program finishes running by checking the busy property of a tab:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set w to do script "sleep 5"
    repeat
        delay 1
        if not busy of w then exit repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Is there a way to catch this notification in applescript

Like
<code>
if gotNotificationMessage
   //do stuff
</code>

Comment: @Timm You could just check if the tab is busy with AppleScript.